# Extract all strings between [ text1 ] [text2] tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have an sql text that includes

```
"Select * from Table Where [PARAM1] = [PARAM2] ..."
```

I want to get list between `"[" "]"` tags to list.

How can I do it ?

Comment: have you tried substring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using LINQ

```
string str = "Select * from Table Where [PARAM1] = [PARAM2] ...";
string[] Array = str.Split().Where(r=> r.StartsWith("[") && r.EndsWith("]"))
                    .Select(r=> r.Trim('[',']'))
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using regular expressions and some LINQ:

```
Regex t = new Regex(@"\[([^]]*)\]");
List<String> parameters = t.Matches(input_string).Cast<Match>().Select(a => a.Groups[1].ToString()).ToList();
```

This will result in a List holding the two matches `PARAM1` and `PARAM2`

Comment: Would you also need to escape the inner ']' on the negated part?

Comment: No you don't. If the first character after a `^` is `]`, then it is automatically escaped (actually this is the only way to say "do not include `]` characters")

Answer (score 2):

Use this snippet

```
string strRegex = @"\[(.*?)\]";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"Select * from Table Where [PARAM1] = [PARAM2] ...";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
   // myMatch.Groups[0] - your string
}
```

Comment: As `+` is greedy, won't this return a single match with everything between the first `[` and the last `]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
List<string> matches=Regex.Matches(@"(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*(?=\])")
                          .Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(x=>x.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
Regex t = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");

string str = @"Select * from Table Where [PARAM1] = [PARAM2] ...";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(str))
{
   // myMatch.Groups[0] and so on....
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://regexr.com?33eel)

Answer (score 0):

To convert a MatchCollection to List use:

```
List<Match> myMatches = Regex.Matches("bla", @"\[[^]]*)\]").Cast<Match>.toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this regular expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[.*?\]");
var parameters = regex.Matches(sqlQueryString);
```